# How to use my local API in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a file `api.js` which contains something along the lines of this:

```
exports.showAll = function(req, res) {
    Obj.find(function(err, Objs) {
        res.send(Objs);
    });
}
```

My server has the line:

```
app.get('/all', api.showAll);
```

When I load `/all` in the browser, I get the JSON, but I want to get this JSON into a client-side JS file, so I can display the JSON data beautifully on a webpage.

How do I use my server-side API in a client-side JS file?

Comment: What you're looking for is [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). This will let you make a request to a server from a client-side script and process the result of that request however you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a call to a server and work with the result, you need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML but the reality is that you can make these kinds of call through other languages and without retrieving XML. Here's a simple example of how to make a request to your server:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // Verify that the request is done and completed successfully
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var json = xhr.responseText;
      var data = JSON.parse(json); // Parse the JSON into an actual object/array
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      console.log('Something went wrong');
    }
  }
};
xhr.open('GET', '/all');
xhr.send();
```